# Different behavior between fieldset and div on Chrome based browsers and other browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

For accessibility purpose it was advice to us to use `fieldset`s instead of `div`s when writing groups of inputs.

I have noticed a weird different behavior between the two tags with the same flex style on Chrome based browsers and some other browsers: in Chrome when using flex on a fieldset it ignores the directive and deal with child elements like they where  block element, even if they are display inline. In other browser the two tags behave the same way.

For example

```
<style>
    .choices {
        display: flex;
    }

    .choices label {
        /* display: inline; /* just for try */
    }

</style>
<fieldset class="choices">
    <label for="choose-1">
        choose 1
        <input type="radio" name="choose-fieldset" id="choose-1">
    </label>
    <label for="choose-2">
        choose 2
        <input type="radio" name="choose-fieldset" id="choose-2">
    </label>
</fieldset>
<div class="choices">
    <label for="choose-3">
        choose 3
        <input type="radio" name="choose-div" id="choose-3">
    </label>
    <label for="choose-4">
        choose 3
        <input type="radio" name="choose-div" id="choose-4">
    </label>
</div>
```

can anyone explain why or how to use a fieldset like a div? It is a bug in Chrome?

browser tested: Brave ko, Chrome ko, Canary ko, Firefox ok, IE ok